# can i upload a web app programmed with google app engine on aws amazon?

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello i want to know can i upload a web app programmed with python on google app engine on a host but not the host of google app engine i have heard about hosts like A W S amazon can i upload my web app on it ?

and also can i upload it on an ordinary host like go daddy ?

i have tried to read but i didn't found a useful information

now i am using this method to upload my file to google app engine cloud

```
google_appengine/appcfg.py update apps/appname
```

note i am on linux and can i use this method to upload it to amazon ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Appscale docs: AppScale is a platform that allows users to deploy and host their own Google App Engine applications. It executes automatically over **Amazon EC2**, Rackspace, Google Compute Engine, Eucalyptus, Openstack, CloudStack, as well as KVM and VirtualBox. It has been developed and is maintained by AppScale Systems, Inc., in Santa Barbara. It supports the Python, Java, Go, and PHP Google App Engine platforms.

More:

- https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki
- List http://www.appscale.com/

Comment: So does (or did) CapeDwarf